# Caching proxy with authenticated REST requests

Tags: authentication, rest, caching-proxy

Consider following scenario:

- I have RESTful URL /articles that returns list of articles
- user provide his credentials using Authorization HTTP header on each request
- articles may vary from user to user based on his privileges

Its possible to use caching proxy, like Squid, for this scenario?
Proxy will see only URL /articles so it may return list of articles only valid for first user that generates the cache. Other users requesting URL /articles can see articles they don't have access to, which is not desirable of course.

Should I roll my own cache or some caching proxy software can be configured to base its cache on Authorization HTTP header?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One possibility to try is using the `Vary: Authorization` response header to instruct downstream caches to be careful about caching by varying the cached documents based on the request's `Authorization` header.

You may already be using this header if you use response-compression. The user generally requests a resource with the header `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`; if the server is configured to support compression, then the response might come with the headers `Content-Encoding: gzip` and `Vary: Accept-Encoding` already.

Comment: Is this even an issue if you use HTTPS? (which should be used if you're using Basic Authentication or Authorization header)

Comment: Depends on the HTTPS implementation. For example, is the cache in front of or behind the SSL terminator?

Comment: @yfeldblum  The phrase "instruct downstream caches to be careful" is too broad. Do you mean to instrcut proxies not to cache responses with authorization header? Or is there a way proxies can handle this smartly? Any useful references will be helpful.

Answer (score 12):

By the HTTP/1.1 RFC section 14.8 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.8):

```
  When a shared cache (see section 13.7) receives a request
  containing an Authorization field, it MUST NOT return the
  corresponding response as a reply to any other request, unless one
  of the following specific exceptions holds:

  1. If the response includes the "s-maxage" cache-control
     directive, the cache MAY use that response in replying to a
     subsequent request. But (if the specified maximum age has
     passed) a proxy cache MUST first revalidate it with the origin
     server, using the request-headers from the new request to allow
     the origin server to authenticate the new request. (This is the
     defined behavior for s-maxage.) If the response includes "s-
     maxage=0", the proxy MUST always revalidate it before re-using
     it.

  2. If the response includes the "must-revalidate" cache-control
     directive, the cache MAY use that response in replying to a
     subsequent request. But if the response is stale, all caches
     MUST first revalidate it with the origin server, using the
     request-headers from the new request to allow the origin server
     to authenticate the new request.

  3. If the response includes the "public" cache-control directive,
     it MAY be returned in reply to any subsequent request.
```

Comment: I think the questioner use `public` flag in `cache-control` header. Your post doesn't answer the question, but it's helpful.